# After integrating Datadog into my Android app, unit tests still pass, but the test process does not exit

Tags: android, robolectric, datadog

I recently integrated Datadog into my Android app. When I later ran unit tests from Gradle, I discovered that my tests were all still passing, but the test process never ended. And on CircleCI, I noticed the build failed with this timeout error message:

```
"Too long with no output (exceeded 10m0s): context deadline exceeded"
```

I experimented with running individual tests in Android Studio and discovered that the same problem exists there, but only when running a Robolectric test. If I run a vanilla JUnit test, then test execution completes as expected.

What's going on, and how can I avoid this problem?

Answer (score 0):

This is not an ideal answer, but I found that I can avoid the problem simply by not calling Datadog.initialize() when unit tests are being run.

First, I added a method to detect that a unit test class is included in the build.

```
  public static boolean isRunningUnitTests() {
    try {
      Class.forName("com.example.myapp.ImportantTest");
      return true;
    } catch (ClassNotFoundException e) {
      return false;
    }
  }
```

Then, at the top of the method where I initialize Datadog, I return immediately if unit tests are being run.

```
  private void initializeDatadog() {
    if (isRunningUnitTests()) {
      // We don't initialize Datadog when running tests, since it will cause the test process
      // to never exit.
      return;
    }

    ....

    Datadog.initialize(this, credentials, configuration, trackingConsent);
  }
```

I have not yet figured out what about the combination of Robolectric and Datadog results in this behavior where the test process never exits.